# Find count value for a different group with reference with single column (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below scenario data. I need a count for column 'c1' with different set of data. total count should be based on unique no of data from column c1 and e1.

```
with t as
(
select 'cab1' as c1, 'ae1' as e1 from dual
union all
select 'cab1' , 'ae2'  from dual
union all
select 'cab1' , 'ae3'  from dual
union all
select 'cab1' , 'ae4'  from dual
union all
select 'cab3' , 'ae1'  from dual
union all
select 'cab3' , 'ae1'  from dual
union all
select 'cab2' , 'ae'  from dual
)
select
 c1,e1, COUNT(*) OVER (partition by c1 order by c1,e1 ) as p1
from t;
```

my result should be

```
c1      e1  count
-----------------------
cab1    ae3 4
cab1    ae2 4
cab1    ae1 4
cab1    ae4 4
cab2    ae  1
cab3    ae1 1
```

Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/4135/0)**

```
with t as
(
select 'cab1' as c1, 'ae1' as e1 from dual
union all
select 'cab1' , 'ae2'  from dual
union all
select 'cab1' , 'ae3'  from dual
union all
select 'cab1' , 'ae4'  from dual
union all
select 'cab3' , 'ae1'  from dual
union all
select 'cab3' , 'ae1'  from dual
union all
select 'cab2' , 'ae'  from dual
)
SELECT
 c1,
 e1,
 COUNT(*) OVER (partition by c1) as p1
FROM t
GROUP BY c1, e1
```

Comment: No need for the `order by  1`, it's useless

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, it is redundant here. Thanks.